# Granting read only access to a view in user-defined database in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, login-script

I have a view called 'cust_view' in a SQL Azure database.

My goal is to give end users of my application read only access to some data in the application database, so they can run their ad-hoc queries from their side by directly connecting to the application database in SQL Server Management Studio or some other business intelligence tool.

**Question** In T-SQL script given below, are some statements unnecessary to meet this goal?

```
--connect to master database from SSMS.
CREATE LOGIN [readonly] WITH PASSWORD=N'61*4#@amz'
GO


--connect to user database
CREATE USER [readonly] FOR LOGIN [readonly]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readonly'
GO


CREATE VIEW cust_view
   AS
   SELECT * FROM Calls;//add whatever other join you would like to expose more data from related tables
GO

GRANT SELECT ON cust_view TO [readonly]
GO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using a [contained database user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff929188) for your app, rather than a login and user. In general, this is the recommended approach on Azure SQL Database: you get better performance because the app can authenticate directly to the user database without requiring an extra round-trip to the master database.

Also, if you only want the app to be able to select from cust_view, do not add the user to the 'db_datareader' role. This role allows the user to run a SELECT statement against any table or view in the database, not just your view. Instead, just grant SELECT on your view and nothing else.

Net:

```
CREATE USER [readonly] WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password'
go

-- create your view

GRANT SELECT ON cust_view TO [readonly]
go
```

Comment: Will CREATE USER statement be run against the user-defined database or master database?

Comment: Against user database

Comment: I found that this contained database user is not enabled by default in SQL Azure. In our case, its not. So, I have to create a LOGIN to create a user.

Answer (score 2):

Sunil, contained Database User Authentication is always on in Azure SQL Database V12. V11 does not have it.

Returning to the original question,

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readonly'
GO
```

is basically equivalent to granting SELECT to every object in the database. For least privilege, only your GRANT statement is needed:

```
GRANT SELECT ON cust_view TO [readonly]
GO
```